# Is it possible to enter the burning buildings in Pip Town?

Tags: deathspank

Is it possible to make DeathSpank go inside of the burning buildings inside of Pip Town? If so, what's in there? I kinda missed that part while playing through the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, is not possible entering inside buildings in Pip Town.

The only thing you can do is blowing up the houses but your probably did already because, if I remember well, there was a sidequest connected to them.

Comment: I actually suspect that you can with the "Density" potion, but I missed it when I was up to that part of the game.